# angular ng-repeat with some logic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this object

```
recipe = {
    name : $scope.name,
    ingredients : $scope.ingredients
}
```

I save `ingredients` in two different ways, that are

```
ingredients1 = [{ingredient : 'berry'}, {ingredient : 'honey'}]
ingredients2 = ['berry', 'honey'];
```

In ng-repeat I need to past ingredient depending on the condition;

```
//ingredients1
<li ng-repeat="ingr in recipe.ingredients track by $index">
    <b>{{ingr}}</b>
</li>

//ingredients2
<li ng-repeat="ingr in recipe.ingredients track by $index">
    <b>{{ingr.ingredients}}</b>
</li>
```

Can I make 1 `ng-repeat` for this two situations, with some conditional statements like `if` or `else`?

Comment: what condition? where ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ingr.ingredient` is defined then bind it, else bind `ingr`, *i.e.*:

```
{{!!ingr.ingredient ? ingr.ingredient : ingr}}
```

Try with this code:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var myScope = this;
    myScope.ingredients = [{
      ingredient: 'berry'
    }, {
      ingredient: 'honey'
    }, 'berry', 'honey'];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as c">
  <li ng-repeat="ingr in c.ingredients track by $index">
    <b>{{!!ingr.ingredient ? ingr.ingredient : ingr}}</b>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: actually, you can even simplify it to {{ingr.ingredient || ingr}}.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you'll never have a third variation you could do

```
<li ng-repeat="ingr in recipe.ingredients track by $index">
  {{ingr.ingredient || ingr}}
</li>
```

However, this is not that maintainable.  I think it might be cleaner to delegate this logic to a helper function.

```
<li ng-repeat="ingr in getIngredients(recipe.ingredients)">
  {{ingr}}
</li>


function getIngredients(ingredients) {
  // Logic to flatten your mix of objects and strings
}
```

This would allow you to add/change the model of recipe ingredients while also creating logic that can be separately unit tested

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways, all are worked listed down here.
Here is a [**Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/k1q2MyENbt71kana0zN0?p=preview)

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.array1 = [{ingredient : 'berry'}, {ingredient : 'honey'}]
  $scope.array2 = ['berry', 'honey'];
  $scope.array3 = [{ingredient : 'berry'}, {ingredient : 'honey'}, 'berry', 'honey'];
});
```

```html
    <h1>array 1</h1>
    <li ng-repeat="ingr in array1">
      <b>{{ ingr.ingredient || ingr }}</b>
    </li>

    <h1>array 2</h1>
    <li ng-repeat="ingr in array2">
      <b>{{ ingr.ingredient ? ingr.ingredient : ingr }}</b>
    </li>

    <h1>array 3</h1>
    <li ng-repeat="ingr in array3">
      <b>{{ ingr.ingredient || ingr }}</b>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="ingr in array3">
      <b>{{ ingr.ingredient ? ingr.ingredient : ingr }}</b>
    </li>
```